# How to activate python virtual environment in VSCode terminal

Tags: django

I started learning the Django framework. I am supposed to use VS Code as editor. I created a folder and an environment in the command prompt. I followed a tutorial, after creating the project and the work environment the command was "workon test" (where "test" is my environment) and it works fine in command prompt as it shows:

```
((test)) C:\Users\DELL\projects\telusko>
```

Applying the same steps in VS code terminal but I cannot activate the virtual environment (test).

Help me to get out of this trouble.

Comment: did you check the docs? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment

Comment: It would be better if you provide additional info (e.g. image or code snippets) but in most cases, if you're in the terminal, and the project directory with the activated environment using the `code .` command should activate the environment in VS Code too. anyways you always can manually activate it with `source <env_name>\Scripts\activate` in Windows and `source <env_name>/bin/activate` in Linux

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install virtualenvwrapper

`pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`

Check your env is existed

`lsvirtualenv -b`

Make sure your env **test** is exist in the list
If **test** env exist you need active it using command

`workon test`

Now if **lsvirtualenv -b**  returned a list not included **test** env this mean env You need to create it using the command below:

`mkvirtualenv test`